# How to read HDR envi image in the Java (using GDAL or Opencv)?

Tags: java, opencv, gdal, hdrimages, envi

I have a HDR envi image with 160 bands and this image has 4 GB as size. Each band for each pixel (row, column) has a double value associated (a reflectance value). In addition, each pixel has a geographical point associated.

I can read it by using R packages, such as RASTER. However, my application will be written in Java and I would like to know if someone used some library (such as OpenCV) to read HDR Envi images. I would also accept other libraries in Java.

I just need to read the **reflectance value** and the **geographical point** for each band and for each pixel of a HDR image. This means that: a pixel has 160 different values of reflectance, which generate a graph (band X reflectance). Is it possible to do in Java? Please, I need some example to do it.